# Room Does not Insert Data into Table in Test

Tags: android, android-room, android-instrumentation

I have a test that I'm trying to test my Room database.  When trying to run a test in an inMemory Database, it does not seem like it is inserting data. so the test is failing.

My Table Entity:

```
@Entity
class EpisodesDownload(
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  var id: Long,
  val uuid: String,
  val mediaItemId: String,
  val isDownloaded: Boolean,
  var percentDownloaded: Int,
  val dateDownload: OffsetDateTime?
) {
    fun updatePercentage(percentDownloaded: Int) {
        this.percentDownloaded = percentDownloaded
    }
}
```

The Dao:

```
@Dao
interface EpisodesDownloadDao {

   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   fun insert(episodesDownload: EpisodesDownload): Single<Long>

   @Update
   fun update(episodesDownload: EpisodesDownload): Completable
}
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class EpisodesDownloadTest {
private val db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
   InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext,
   LuminaryRoomDatabase::class.java
   )
  .addMigrations(LuminaryRoomDatabase.MIGRATION_1_2)
  .build()

 private val underTest = db.episodesDownloadDao()

 @Test
 fun update() {
   val entity = EpisodesDownload(
   0,
   UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
   UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
   true,
   100,
   OffsetDateTime.now()
  )

  underTest.insert(entity)
  val list = underTest.selectAllTest() //list.size() is equal to zero

  val updated = entity
  updated.updatePercentage(50)

  underTest.update(updated)

  underTest.selectAllTest().let {
    assertThat(it, hasSize(equalTo(1)))  //fails
    assertThat(it[0], equalTo(updated))
  }
  }
}
```

Is it because I am setting my primary key Id = 0 when it is auto incremented? I am not getting any exceptions when running the code (other than the test failing).

Comment: please show your code for EpisodesDownload class

Comment: @LenaBru it's already up there.

Comment: please see if insert returns a long that is other than 0

Comment: @LenaBru - thanks for your comment, this led me to the reason I was not seeing an insert.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was returning a Single from the room database, I needed to change my code to:

```
val insertedId = underTest.insert(entity)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .subscribe()
val list = underTest.selectAllTest()

val updated = entity
updated.updatePercentage(50)
updated.id = list[0].id

underTest.update(updated)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .subscribe()
```